# Difficulty understanding function syntax

Tags: scala

I can understand this:

```
scala> def f(i: Int) = "dude: " + i
f: (i: Int)java.lang.String

scala> f(3)
res30: java.lang.String = dude: 3
```

It defines a function f that takes an int and returns a string that is of the form dude: + the int that is passed in.

Now the same function can be specified like this:

```
val f: Int => String = x => "dude: " + x
scala> f(3)
res31: String = dude: 3
```

- Why do we need two `=>`
- What does `String = x` mean? I thought that when you want to define something in Scala you'd do `x:String`?

Comment: It's really best to keep in mind the distinction between methods and functions. `def` defines methods, which are not first-class values. There are various means of defining functions, which are first-class values. The distinction is easily blurred, especially when the compiler automatically "lifts" a method to a function by silently applying "partial application" to turn a method (possibly with some arguments fixed) into a function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should parse it as

```
val (f: Int => String) = (x => "dude: " + x)
```

So it specifies that f has type `(Int => String)` and is defined as an anonymous function which takes an `Int` parameter `(x)` and returns a `String`.

Comment: One thing never changes and helps humans visually parse Scala definitions and expersions: The sole `=` _always_ separates the signature (name and type(s)) from the value defined.

Another thing to remember is that `=>` associates to the right.

Answer (score 6):

Only to clarify a bit. `def` statements defines methods, not functions.

Now, for the function. You could have written it this way:

```
val f: (Int => String) = x => "dude: " + x
```

And it could be read as "f is a function from Int to String". So, answering your question, a `=>` in a type position mean function from type to type, while `=>` in a value position means takes parameter `identifier` and returns `expression`.

Further, it can also rely on the type inferrer:

```
val f = (x:Int) => "dude: " + x
```

Comment: @pedrofuria do you have a reference that def only define methods not functions?  I thought a function was a method when it belonged to an object.

Comment: Functions never "belong" to anything. That's part of how they become first-class values that may "flow freely" through your program. The real distinction is that methods are a JVM thing while functions are a Scala construct.

Answer (score 3):

Both Lee and pedrofurla gave excellent answers.  I'll also add that if you want your method to be converted to a function (for passing as a parameter, use as a partially applied function, etc), you can use the magic underbar:

```
def foo(i: Int) = "dude: " + x
val bar = foo _  // now you have a function bar of type Int => String
```